# Check default sim setting of voice call

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi i want to check sim setting for voice call such as Always Ask, SIM1 or SIM 2.

If it is always ask i want to give alert to user. Please set either sim 1 or sim 2

Is it possible to check in xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to check in xamarin?

Yes, you can use `DependencyService` to achieve it.

First of all, create a Interface like following code.

```
   public interface ISimService
    {
        int GetSimNum();
    }
```

Then achieve this interface in the Droid folder.

```
using Android.Content.PM;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android.Telephony;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using GetSimNumber;
using GetSimNumber.Droid;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Lang.Reflect;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SimNumber))]
namespace GetSimNumber.Droid
{
    public class SimNumber : ISimService
    {
        Context context =Android.App.Application.Context;
        public int GetSimNum()
        {





            SubscriptionManager sm = (SubscriptionManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonySubscriptionService);


            int subscriberId=-1;

           if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                subscriberId = SubscriptionManager.DefaultDataSubscriptionId;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Class cls = sm.Class;
                    Method method = cls.GetDeclaredMethod("getDefaultDataSubId");
                    subscriberId = (int)method.Invoke(sm,null);
                }
                catch (Java.Lang.Exception e) { e.PrintStackTrace(); }
            }
            return subscriberId;



        }
    }
}
```

Add the `READ_PHONE_STATE` following permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Note: you need to achieve the runtime permission to request `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Here is running GIF.

[image]

the value of represent is like following explanation.

- -1 - No SIM card
- 1 - SIM 1 card
- 2 - SIM 2 card

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.